# Improve SEO by forcing web crawlers to read csv file searching for keywords

Tags: seo, javascript, csv

I am trying to improve the seo of my website and I recently used an online seo tester for my first custom-coded website.

I am trying to improve the number of unique keywords and textual content crawled and I'm hoping to use the `.csv` file I created for the plotly.js sunburst. I followed this example https://plot.ly/javascript/sunburst-charts/#large-number-of-slices.

Right now I think the best way is to allow access to the `.csv` would be using the `robots.txt` file but I have not been able to confirm that approach will help. I'm new to the web development world so I apologize if the question is primitive. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting to use this "list of keywords" (`.csv` file) to somehow improve the ranking of _other_ pages? `robots.txt` is really for _blocking_ access. You don't need to do anything with `robots.txt` if you want to allow access.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by " allow access to the .csv"? If you host the file publicly to your server, Google can find it and index it without any issues.

That being said, there are ways for you to make sure they find it, such as linking to this .csv file from withing a page or submitting it using an XML sitemap.

Do a search on Google for:

```
filetype:csv sunburst
```

and you'll see plenty of CSV files indexed by them.